# Bintray is offline how to create android builds

Tags: react-native, fastlane, bintray

Since yesterday i Bintray is offline https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml i have issue to create Android builds via Fastlane is there any way to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to make the builds:
React Native Project using Fastline on the Folder android => build.grandle file you can replace "jcenter()" with "mavenCentral() and grandlePluginPortal()".